# Search worked now it's not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi Guys for some reason my search function that worked does not work anymore I have tried variety of like / or_like to no avail could someone please lend a hand here is my controllers code:

```
        function contractor(){
            $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');

            $this->db->like($keyword);
            $this->db->like('contractor_location',$keyword);
            $this->db->like('contractor_email',$keyword);
            $this->db->like('contractor_description',$keyword);
            $this->db->like('contractor_number',$keyword);
            $this->db->like('contractor_website',$keyword);
            $this->db->join('category','contractors.contractorID=category_name.catagory_id','inner');
            $this->db->group_by('contractor.contractorID');
            $query = $this->db->get('contractors');
            return $query->result();
    }
```

UPDATE:
Here is the error message I am receiving sorry I forgot to add it:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' AND `contractor_location` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE
'!' AND `contr' at line 4
 SELECT * FROM `contractors` INNER JOIN `category` ON
`contractors`.`contractorID`=`category_name`.`catagory_id` WHERE LIKE
'%%' ESCAPE '!' AND `contractor_location` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' AND
`contractor_email` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' AND `contractor_description`
LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' AND `contractor_number` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' AND
`contractor_website` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' GROUP BY
`contractor`.`contractorID`

Filename: modules/search/models/Search_m.php

Line Number: 38
```

Comment: What `Doesn't work` means ? No results? Errors ? Have you made any research (var_dumps, manual queries on DB, etc. ) ?

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to add the error please see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code miss column name

```
    $this->db->like($keyword);
```

And you have error in table join

```
 $this->db->join('category','contractors.contractorID=category_name.catagory_id','inner');
```

Corrected code:

```
function contractor(){
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $this->db->like('contractor_location',$keyword);
        $this->db->like('contractor_email',$keyword);
        $this->db->like('contractor_description',$keyword);
        $this->db->like('contractor_number',$keyword);
        $this->db->like('contractor_website',$keyword);
        $this->db->join('category','contractors.contractorID=category.catagory_id','inner');
        $this->db->group_by('contractor.contractorID');
        $query = $this->db->get('contractors');
        return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo's there! Search is working but I had to change some of your answer till I got the desired results. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It is missing a column name

`WHERE LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'`

you need to correct this line `$this->db->like($keyword);`

Answer (score 0):

Final Working Code is as Follows:

```
        function contractor(){
            $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
            $location = $this->input->post('location');
            $industry = $this->input->post('industry');

            $this->db->like('contractor_name',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->like('contractor_location',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->like('contractor_email',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->like('contractor_description',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->like('contractor_number',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->like('contractor_website',$keyword,$industry,$location);
            $this->db->join('catagory','contractors.contractorID=catagory.ID','inner');
            $this->db->group_by('contractors.contractorID');
            $query = $this->db->get('contractors');
            return $query->result();
    }
```